# Possible to check out a specific branch using gitosis

Tags: git, gitosis

I have gitosis setup and working wonderfully using ssh. git@domain.com:repository.git works just as expected. Can clone, push, pull, etc.

I was wondering if I can use git to pull a specific branching however. git@domain.com:repository.git/somebranchname for example

didn't know if this was possible and haven't found any examples so I'm guessing no, but not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, when you clone a Git repo, you get everything (all tags and branches). However, they'll be stored as remote branches. Assuming the name of the remote is `origin` (which it is by default), you can checkout a local branch using:

```
$ git checkout -b somebranchname origin/somebranchname
```

which will create a local branch called `somebranchname` that contains the contents of `somebranchname` in Gitosis' copy of the repo. It will also "track" the remote branch so `git pull` will continue to pull in the latest changes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply mipadi. I found that I could do it for ruby apps with capistrano. Have been manually uploading updates to a few of my apps and that has become way to involved. for ruby capistrano will solve this problem. I've got a few c# apps that i'll have to find another solution for.